# Is this the vent?

Tags: plumbing, drain-waste-vent

Below is an image below my kitchen.

1. The drain for the sink.  I can hear the water run through it
2. Junction
3. Connects to the 3" main drain
4. Is this a vent? I don't hear any water going through it and I can't figure out what else it could be hooked up to
5. Sump pump

Is number 4 a vent and could I tie into it for my [basement dishwasher](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/30468/how-can-i-install-a-sink-dishwasher-in-basement)?

Edited: Updated to the real pict I meant to post
[image]

Comment: No image showing.

Comment: If it's a 1 1/4 or greater pipe that's running up where there's no fixtures above, then it's likely a vent.  Can't tell for sure without a photo.

Comment: We can't see where the pipes are going or where they came from.  More pics would help.

Comment: If you look at [this diagram](http://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/30468/how-can-i-install-a-sink-dishwasher-in-basement) the picture is taken from the bottom doorway looking down on the dwg.  Ignore the bottom sump pipe. The one the runs off the left of the pict connects to the dotted drain.  The kitchen sink drains from the pipe above the beam and runs off the left of the pict.  So I'm guessing the pipe the T's off of it is the vent??

Comment: The vent connection to the main stack is normally above the "bottom of the sink/tub line"  If you are taking this picture from your basement looking up and all of the pipes are shooting down and then into the stack... Then I would say none of these are vents.  The pipe that is against the wall could be.

Comment: The pipe on the wall is for the sump pump ejection.  The pipe that is T'd runs up from the T, so that'd fit your description of "above the bottom of the sink/tube line"

Comment: Sink vents should take off from the trap arm before or right at where the drain turns down into a vertical pipe. A vent after a vertical pipe would be illegal. Not to say someone didn't try to do this. Also trap arms must be somewhat short, the run to the alleged vent is much too long. I doubt it's a vent.